# What is the difference between <hr> and <v-divider>?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Consider two cases:

1.

```
<v-container>
  <!--Some code here-->
</v-container>
<v-divider></v-divider>
```

2. 

```
<v-container>
  <!--Some code here-->
</v-container>
<hr>
```

Is the difference only in color and height or some other aspects as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v-divider` is just a component wrapper of `hr` element with some styles and props like :

- direction, you could add  `vertical` prop to make vertical
- color mode dark/light
- inset to translate it.